# R writing operations into a function and iterating

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, stringr

I have this input (sample):

```r
input <- tibble(
  minimum_term = c("None", "6 Months", "12 Months"),
  maximum_term = c("None", "18 Months", "24 Months"),
  other_cols
)
```

and I would like to get to this output:

```r
desired_output <- tibbe(
  minimum_term = c(0, 6, 12),
  maximum_term = c(0, 18, 24),
  other_cols
)
```

How could I write the following more succinctly (maybe in a function and using `purrr::map`?)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

input <- input %>% 
  mutate(minimum_term = str_replace(
    minimum_term,
    'None',
    "0"
  )
  )

input <- input %>% 
  mutate(minimum_term = str_extract(minimum_term, '[0-9]{1,2}'))

output <- input %>% 
  mutate(minimum_term = as.numeric(minimum_term))
```

1. The first operation is to take `minimum_term` from data frame `input` and replace all instances of "None" with "0".
2. Second operation is then to extract the numbers.
3. Third is to convert to a numeric.

I have more columns similar to `minimum_term` so I'm keen to put this into a pipeable function and use `purrr`, but unsure how to do this, my first try:

```r
term_replacement <- function(df, x){
  df <- df %>% 
    mutate(x = str_replace(
       x,
      'None',
      "0"
    )
  )
  df <- df %>% 
    mutate(x = str_extract(x, '[0-9]{1,2}'))
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(x = as.numeric(x))
}
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks, have done just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are multiple columns, use `across`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
term_replacement <- function(df, cols){
      df %>%
           mutate(across(all_of(cols), ~ replace_na(readr::parse_number(.), 0)))
}
```

Call the function as (change the column names as needed)

```
term_replacement(input, c("minimum_term", "maximum_term"))
```

0utput

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  minimum_term maximum_term
         <dbl>        <dbl>
1            0            0
2            6           18
3           12           24
```